# Preserve order and Conditionally disable button

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a piece of javascript that Increments or decrements numbers and prints in console.

Here is my code.

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 4;
var step = 4;
var max = 13;

function incr() {
  console.log(a + '\t' + b);
  a = b+1;
  b = b + step;
  if (b >= max)
    b = max

}

function dec() {
  console.log(a + '\t' + b);
  a = a - step;
  if (a <= 0)
    a = 0;
  b = b - step;

  console.log(a + '\t' + b);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="incr()">
  Increment
</button>
<button onclick="dec()">
  Decrement
</button>
```

Here my requirement is as below.

When I Increment, the order that I get in console is

```
0  4
5  8
9  12
13  13
```

when I decrement, it should be decrementing like the below order.

```
9  12
5  8
0  4
```

instead it is coming as

```
10  9
10  9
6   5
6   5
2   1
2   1
0   -3
```

Also is there a way that I can disable Increment button when b is 13 and disable Decrement button when a is 0?

Thanks

Comment: Is the first interval for the `a` variable 5 by intention? Just wondering because subsequent steps are 4.

Comment: Hi @obscure I've added first interval of `a` as `5` 'coz the second time I click, it should be `5 8`, if I didn't add it, it was giving me `4 8`

Comment: Why should it be `9  12`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't find a pattern in your sequence that would be easily transferable into code. So I'd recommend you store the desired values for the `a` and `b` variables inside an array element, increment/decrement a counter and display the values from the corresponding array element instead.

A HTML Button element can be easily activated and deactivated using it's `.disabled` property. To access your buttons using JavaScript you need to give 'em an unique id and get a reference via `document.getElementById("buttonId")`.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("decrementButton").disabled = true;

var currentElement = -1;
var sequences = [{a:0, b:4}, {a:5, b:8}, {a:9, b:12}, {a:13, b:13}];
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

function incr() {
  currentElement++;
  refreshVariables();
}

function dec() {
  currentElement--;
  refreshVariables();
}

function refreshVariables() {
  a = sequences[currentElement].a;
  b = sequences[currentElement].b;

  if (a == 0) {
    document.getElementById("decrementButton").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("decrementButton").disabled = false;
  }
  if (b == 13) {
    document.getElementById("incrementButton").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incrementButton").disabled = false;
  }
  console.log(a + '\t' + b);
}
```

```html
<button id="incrementButton" onclick="incr()">
  Increment
</button>
<button id="decrementButton" onclick="dec()">
  Decrement
</button>
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I hard coded into my explanation as well.

Comment: It be easier then just make switch with values and console.log... I don't think that's the wanted behavior. I do respect the intention no fuss there.